# I need help writing a code for this question

Tags: macos, pycharm

Im using pycharm

Write a program that will calculate tax on the user's annual salary. It must  :
1. ask the user to enter their name,
2. ask the user to enter their annual salary
3. print their tax bill on screen

However, Australian tax laws are complicated.

They follow these rules:

•0 – $18,200    Nil ($0 tax paid)

•$18,201 – $45,000           19 cents for each $1 over $18,200

•$45,001 – $120,000        $5,092 plus 32.5 cents for each $1 over $45,000

•$120,001 – $180,000     $29,467 plus 37 cents for each $1 over $120,000

•$180,001 and over,          $51,667 plus 45 cents for each $1 over $180,000

Comment: What did you try so far? Looks like a simple use of consecutive `if` (and/or `elif`) would do the trick.

Comment: Im very new to coding and not sure what code to write for calculating the tax paid

Comment: this all i got so far


n=input('enter your name')

print(n)

s=input('enter your annual salary')

print(s)

if s<=18200:

    tax=s*1

elif s>=18201:

    tax=

Comment: You seem to know how to use `if`, so go ahead and write branches for each of the tax rates.  If you get stuck, then [edit] your question with your non-working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function works and does not require any dependencies to work.

```
def taxesDue(x:float):
    '''Function that takes in a person's yearly salary (unit: AUD) and returns the taxes due (unit: AUD)'''
    if(x <= 18200):
        return 0                         # lucky person
    elif(x <= 45000):
        return round(0.19*(x-18200), 2)
    elif(x<= 120000):
        return round(5092+0.325*(x-45000), 2)
    elif(x <= 180000):
        return round(29467+0.37*(x-120000),2)
    else:
        return round(51667+0.45*(x-180000)*0.45, 2)
```

The sample output is

```
taxesDue(16500)
>0 

taxesDue(18201)
>0.19

taxesDue(1e6) # scientific notation for 1 million (float)
>217717.0
```

Since all of us were new to coding at one point. Some explanation on things you will likely encounter on your journey deeper into Python.

1. The function's input is the salary in AUD (can be an integer like `20000` or a `float` such as `20000.95` where the decimals represent cents. Therefore, I rounded the taxes due to two digits through `round(y, 2)`. In case the input salary is always of type `int` you can leave the rounding out as the output will naturally only have two decimals.
2. Speaking of `float` and `int`. Types in Python are dynamic so the `float:x` in the function's argument list is syntactic sugar (nice to look at for the developer/user but no impact on the rest of the code) to emphasize that a floating point number (the salary) goes in rather than a string `str` like `x=Hello IRS`. Note that `int` is a subset of `float` so `float` is more general.
3. The `if`/`elif`/`else` iterates through the conditions (e.g. `x <= 45000`). `elif` and the final `else` is only checked if none of the previous conditions was met. Note that this naturally reflects your task at hand.
4. Any function is exited as soon as any of the `return`'s is reached.
5. Comments such as `#lucky` or the the comment right underneath the function's head `'''Function...` will go into the docstring. In turn, the developer can retrieve it when running

```
?taxesDue
```

[image]

If you need to print the result run

```
x = 475000       # or whatever salary you can think of
print(taxesDue(x))
```